# Python's UTF-8 encoding yields odd results even though explicit utf-8 encoding is used

Tags: python, json, encoding, utf-8

I am parsing some JSON (specifically Amazon reviews file, which Amazon publicly provides). I am doing a line by line parsing with conversion to Pandas DataFrame and insert to SQL on the fly. I found something really odd. I use UTF-8 to open the json file. In the file itself when I open it with notepad I don't see any strange symbols or whatever. For example, substring of review:

```
The temperature control doesn’t hold to as tight a temperature as some of the others reported.
```

But when I parse it and check the contents of string:

```
The temperature control doesn\xe2\x80\x99t hold to as tight a temperature as some of the others reported.
```

Why is that so? How I can't properly read it?

My current code is below:

```
def parseJSON(path):
  g = io.open(path,'r',encoding='utf8')
  for l in g:
      yield eval(l)



for l in parseJSON(r"reviews.json"):
    for review in l["reviews"]:
        df = {}
        df[l["url"]] = review["review"]
        dfInsert = pd.DataFrame( list(df.items()), columns = ["url", "Review"])
```

File subset which fails is there:
http://www.filedropper.com/subset

Comment: why are you using `eval` instead of `json.loads(...)`? That's probably your problem.  Also python2 or python3?

Comment: @AnthonySottile it is 2.7.13 |Continuum Analytics, Inc. With json.loads() result is exactly same

Comment: how is the file written?

Comment: Can you post URL from Amazon?

Comment: No idea how it was written I just downloaded it from other guys. I can dump the file somewhere if it is needed.

Comment: That apostrophe in `doesn’t` isn't a plain single-quote `'` == `\x27`, it's RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK == `\u2019`.

Comment: If you want to get rid of fancy quotes etc & replace them with their plain ASCII equivalents, take a look at [Unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode). It's better to make your program handle Unicode properly, but that's not always an option.

Comment: @PM2Ring thank you for link to Unidecode. Actually it works like charm. Of course, we loose details of UTF8 but it is ok in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should never parse a text from an unsafe (online) source with [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval). If the data is in [JSON](http://json.org), you should use a JSON parser. That's why JSON was invented - to provide a safe serialization and deserialization.

In your case, use [`json.load()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load) from the standard [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module:

```
import json

def parseJSON(path):
    return json.load(io.open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig'))
```

Since your JSON file contains a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), you should use the codec that knows how to strip it, i.e. the [`utf-8-sig`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#encodings-and-unicode).

If your file contains **one JSON Object per line**, you can read it like this:

```
def parseJSON(path):
    with io.open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
        for line in f:
            yield json.loads(line)
```

---

Now to answer why are you seeing `doesn\xe2\x80\x99t` instead of `doesn’t`. If you decode the bytes `\xe2\x80\x99` as UTF-8, you get:

```
>>> '\xe2\x80\x99'.decode('utf8')`
u'\u2019'
```

and what Unicode codepoint is that?

```
>>> unicodedata.name(u'\u2019')
'RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK'
```

Ok, now what happens when you `eval()` it in Python 2? Well, first, note that Unicode is not really a first-class citizen in the land of Python 2 strings (Python 3 fixed that).

So, `eval` tries to parse the string (series of bytes in Python 2) as a Python expression:

```
>>> eval('"’"')
'\xe2\x80\x99'
```

Note that (in my console that uses UTF-8) even when I type `’`, that's represented as a sequence of 3 bytes.

It doesn't even help to say it's supposed to be a `unicode`:

```
>>> eval('u"’"')
u'\xe2\x80\x99'
```

What will help is to tell Python how to interpret the series of bytes that follow in the source/string, i.e. what's the encoding (see [PEP-263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)):

```
>>> eval('# encoding: utf-8\nu"’"')
u'\u2019'
```

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. But json.loads yields exactly same result. The issue for me happens down the line when I try to load this stuff into SQL and get the error that it can't decode this byte. Hence I thought that something is wrong on the file read step.

Comment: Am I right that even if I see such output that doesn't necessarily mean that the file wasn't read properly?

Comment: There's no way `eval` handled unicode properly. But the only way we can test where is the problem it that you give as the sample input that fails.

Comment: @MaximHaytovich, see the update for one JSON object per line.

Comment: Thank you, makes perfect sense. Though in such case it seem I have to repeat same stuff for every odd symbol I can face in file - or rely on Unidecode or smth like it?

Comment: Absolutely not. If you know the character encoding (in this case UTF-8 with byte-order-mark, which is standard on Windows), and if you know the content encoding (in this case JSON), you don't have to worry about  decoding -- `io` reader and `json` decoder will take care of that. The second part of my answer is *only* an explanation why `eval` can't decode your unicode file properly. Btw, when you don't know which encoding it is, you can use `chardet` for detection and `iconv` for conversion to UTF-8.